# Calling an Oracle procedure with an IN OUT parameter type from Groovy

Tags: oracle, groovy, package, procedure

I have searched on this and tried many things so I'm hoping someone can help me.

I have an Oracle package that contains a procedure with the following parameters:

```
  PROCEDURE g$_verify_password1_prd
      ( p_object   IN     VARCHAR2,
        p_version  IN     VARCHAR2,
        p_password IN OUT VARCHAR2,
        p_role     OUT    VARCHAR2 )
```

This is an API call and is written by our vendor, I cannot modify it and do not wish to.  My problem is with the p_password IN OUT parameter.  What is the syntax to call this from Groovy?  I discovered Sql.inout when searching for an answer to this but cannot get it to take.  Here is my code, please keep in mind I've tried many things and this is simply where I left off:

```
sql.call '{call G$_SECURITY.G$_VERIFY_PASSWORD1_PRD(?, ?, ?, ?)}', 
    [$p_object, p_version, ${Sql.inout(Sql.VARCHAR(p_password))}, Sql.VARCHAR], 
    { p_password, p_rol ->
        //p_password = p_pass
        p_role = p_rol
        println p_password
        println p_rol
    }
```

I continually get errors similar to:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _SECURITY for class: banner.CheckSecurityService
    at banner.CheckSecurityService.SecurityCheck(CheckSecurityService.groovy:49)
    at banner.Hello2Service.main(Hello2Service.groovy:20)
```

If I remove the `sql.inout` and just pass in a variable, it runs but is not correct because it's not then returning the password variable from Oracle.  I've successfully called numerous procedures from this package without issue until the IN OUT parameter so there has to be something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Looking at the error, the problem is with `G$_SECURITY`, specifically, `$_SECURITY`. When prepend with `$` `_SECURITY` is treated as variable. Are you using double quotes `"` in the application, I see you have used `'` in question though.

Comment: That's why I said that I've "successfully called numerous procedures from this package without issue".  :)  I ran into the $ issue previously and corrected it.  If I get rid of the sql.inout and just pass in a variable and continue using the same package name with the $, the error goes away but the behavior is not what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql can be of something like:

```
sql.call '{call G$_SECURITY.G$_VERIFY_PASSWORD1_PRD(?, ?, ?, ?)}', 
    [$p_object, p_version, Sql.inout(Sql.VARCHAR(p_password)), Sql.VARCHAR], 
    { p_password, p_rol ->
        //p_password = p_pass
        p_role = p_rol
        println p_password
        println p_rol
    }
```

*Untested with database directly.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you were the same person commenting as above.  This did it, thank you so much dmahapatro!  I think I tried so many options I was confused after a while.  I will mark it as the correct answer.  I appreciate your help greatly.